# Android Emulator in Visual Studio: unsecure connection when connecting to the internet

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I'm working with Xamarin in Visual Studio. When I try to access the internet on my emulator, It wont load any webpages.

Error: connection is not private.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHM3c.png)

Comment: Are you running some man in the middle service such as Fiddler, Charles Proxy or mitmproxy?

Comment: @Cheesebaron not that I know of. I have this ESET Security thing on my computer though, does that affect anything?